# Homeomorphism $A_n=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \;|\; 0<|x|\leq 1 \}$ and $B_n=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \;|\;1\leq |x| \}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $A_n=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \;|\; 0<|x|\leq 1 \}$ and $B_n=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \;|\;1\leq |x| \}$, Are $A_n, B_n $ Homeomorphic?

Comment: I'm quite sure that $f\colon B_n \to A_n$ given by $f(x) = 2x/(1+\|x\|)$ is a homeomorphism..

Comment: I agree with rldias. If you draw both the regions you'll see that they are actually inverted image of each other.

Comment: g(x) = x/(2-\|x\|) is the inverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I invite you to prove that the function  $f\colon B_n\to A_n$ given by $f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{1+|x|}$ is a homeomorphism.

Another (maybe more intuitive) way to see it is the following: looking at $B_n$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and knowing that the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{S}^n$ (via stereographic projection), we can see that $B_n$ is taken to a punctured disk in $\mathbb{S}^n$, which is obviously homeomorphic to $A_n$.

Comment: I can not believe I had not seen it, thank you very much